# Group Pandas: How to concat or merge/join/append two csv files with same index but different extensions in grouped data?

Tags: pandas, group-concat

I'd like to concat or merge or append/join two csv files with the same indix ID but different extensions on the same ID. The data are grouped by ID also. The 1st file looks like this:

```
ID,year,age
810006862,2000,49
810006862,2001,
810006862,2002,
810006862,2003,52
810023112,2003,27
810023112,2004,28
810023112,2005,29
810023112,2006,30
810033622,2000,24
810033622,2001,25
```

and the 2nd file looks like this:

```
    ID,year,from1,to1
810006862,2002,15341,15705
810006862,2003,15706,16070
810006862,2004,16071,16436
810006862,2005,,
810023112,2000,14610,14975
810023112,2001,14976,15340
810023112,2003,15825,16523
810033622,2000,13211,14876
810033622,2001,14761,14987
```

I have set index of ID for both files after reading it to dataframe, and then concat them together, but it gets error message of "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (25, 2914), indices imply (25, 251)"

I've tried the following codes:

```
sp = pd.read_csv('sp1.csv')
sp = sp.set_index('ID')
op = pd.read_csv('op1.csv')
op = op.set_index('ID')
ff = pd.concat([sp, op], join = 'outer', sort = False, axis = 1)
```

I've also tried concat the two files together without setting up index, and the result seemed having correct rows, but the horizontal values were incorrect related. 
I've also tried merge as well, but it came with many unnecessary duplicated rows within each group. Since each group has different year and age, I found quite difficult to delete those newly generated rows using this method.

```
full = pd.merge(sp, op, on = 'ID', how = 'outer', sort = False)
```

Maybe somebody can suggest ways to easily delete these duplicates, and this will also work for me, because the merged file became so huge! Thanks in advance!

Expected results would be including all different values from both csv files. It is somewhat like this:

```
    ID,year,age,from1,to1
810006862,2000,49,,
810006862,2001,,,
810006862,2002,,15341,15705
810006862,2003,52,15706,16070
810006862,2004,,16071,16436
810006862,2005,,,
810023112,2000,,14610,14975
810023112,2001,,14976,15340
810023112,2003,27,15825,16523
810023112,2004,28,,
810023112,2005,29,,
810023112,2006,30,,
810033622,2000,24,13211,14876
810033622,2001,25,14761,14987
```

I've searched online for similar posts along for quite some time, but unable to solve my problem. Can anybody offer any clue how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jezrael I've just tried your code, the result is actually very close to what I want except that I have two identical column name of year in the two files. The year rows was unable to merge to one.  It's like this :            ID  year_x   age  group  year_y    from1      to1
0   810006862  2000.0  49.0      0  2002.0  15341.0  15705.0
1   810006862  2001.0   NaN      1  2003.0  15706.0  16070.0
2   810006862  2002.0   NaN      2  2004.0  16071.0  16436.0
3   810006862  2003.0  52.0      3  2005.0      NaN      NaN
4   810023112  2003.0  27.0      0  2000.0  14610.0  14975.0

Comment: It seems only takes the ID year from the 1st file. For example, for ID# 810006862, it shows result from year 2000 from year 2003, and it didn't show year 2004 and 2005 from the 2nd file. This is to your 2nd version, and i'll try the last one

Comment: The last version somewhat similar like the 2nd version. It somehow could not pick the years from the 2nd file with the same ID. I've worked on this for quite some time, but couldn't find a way to sort this out. I wonder what is the key word to search for this type of problem and solutions.

Comment: I dont understand why is first row `810006862,2000,49` matched with `810006862,2002,15341,15705` to `810006862,2000,49,15341,15705`? Not problem different years 2000 and 2002?

Comment: Thank you for your question@jezrael. Actually I think I've made an error when I tried to manually generate an expected result. I will double check the two files and the codes and get back to you.

Comment: And also please test `full = pd.merge(sp, op, on = ['ID', 'year'], how = 'outer', sort = False)`

Comment: Thanks a lotttt! I need to go and will try this evening! and get back to you. I'll update my post with correct expected results!

Comment: @jezrael Hi again. Thanks a bunch! I tried your last code, which I believe it was the 2nd code you offered earlier today, and it worked!!! The reason I didn't figure it out all at once then was because the result was not totally in the same order as my manually created result. I've checked the rows one by one and it's correct. Now all I need to do is just regroup them by ID. Also I've updated my question so others can benefit from this too! Thumbs up to you! Also I am very new to this too, and wondering what I need to do so you can get credit from helping me as well. Thanks a lot!